# Do we add normal header and footer in Google Accelerated Mobile Pages?

Tags: html, amp-html

I've just started working on AMP when it struck me; Do we add page header and footer as usual? Without JS elements of course.

Today, this page has a fairly large drop down menu and footer with a lot of content. Do I add this to my AMP page?

Answer (score 1):

In AMP, there is no restriction on your layout. You can include header and footer, but they should compliance.

Here is official guide on layout. [AMP HTML FORMAT](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md)